# Effective AI for 3D Motion

Tags: xna, ai, path-finding

I am developing a game in XNA and am trying to create an effective AI for the enemy and friendly spaceships but am having a hard time keeping the game effective without disadvantaging one side or the other (deliberately). My current setup is as follows:

1. Ship targets enemy based on proximity.
2. Ship changes direction and moves toward target, firing when in range. Ship fires single repeater weapon in the forward direction.
3. Ship will not change direction when closer than certain distance from enemy.
4. If you are directly following and shooting at a ship, the ship does not attempt to evade fire. (consequence of #3)
5. All ships have similar firepower.

I am trying to improve this system and am willing to rewrite if necessary. Most of the ships end up flying around each other, shooting but never hitting. I have thought of several ideas to improve it:

1. Once health drops significantly, ship will boost away from firing ship.
2. Some ships are randomly chosen to be equipped with torpedoes (maybe add aft firing?).
3. Make ships more wary of attacking cruisers (they tend to die quickly when attacking).

Does anyone have any other suggestions as to improve the AI of the ships? Does anyone have a completely different system of doing this?

Comment: you have sea or space ships? I think that the sea, but you used the word "flying"

Comment: Spaceships. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You're looking for improvements, but it's not clear what is the issue at hand? Is it _Most of the ships end up flying around each other, shooting but never hitting._? If it's the case, it's not clear that the suggestions you've added try to solve it...

Comment: Which is one reason why I am thinking of rewriting it completely, and wanted to know if anyone had made an effective system for enemy AI.

Comment: If your ships flying one around another, and you dont want they do that, so do not order them to do so. Huh? And only AI system I know is Minecraft AI system, but I think it's totally enough for begin.

Comment: Can you tell us more about these ships' capabilities? Eg. Do their weapons fire straight along their forward direction or can they turret/aim (in which case it sounds like your target leading in your aiming code isn't correct). What's their steering/acceleration model? More generally, what are the criteria by which you want this AI to be improved? Eg. do you want more decisive encounters (quick lethal resolution) or more showy displays (longer, drawn out, more manoeuvring & less killing), etc. At the moment you've left this very open-ended about what goals you want to achieve with this AI.

Comment: @DMGregory They fire straight forward, do not turret, and keep a constant speed. I would like more maneuvering but also more killing as the current AI doesn't work too well.

Comment: If you do rewrite, you may want to try digging into "steering behaviors," if your implementation doesn't already use them. As for getting "more killing" - it depends on why their attacks are ineffective. If they aim correctly at a stationary target, but not a moving target, you may need to change the aim calculations to lead the targets. If they do that already, then perhaps consider simply raising projectile speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Basic AI Steering Behaviours**

- **Seek** *(steer towards target, and accelerate)*
- **Flee** *(steer away from target, and accelerate)*

### **Smarter ai steering behaviours:**

- **Pursue** *(steer towards target's destination [position+velocity*amt])*
- **Evade** *(steer away from target's destination [position+velocity*amt] )*
- **Approach** *(steer towards target, but slow down once within a certain distance, and try to stay in that radius)*

### Even Smarter ai steering behaviours:

- **Evade Projectiles** *(Either evade their current position, or their destination)*

### Other ai behaviours

- **Shoot at Target's Destination**
- **Flocking**
- **Pathfollowing** *(set a specific path to follow with repeat or ping pong effects)*
- **Pathfinding** *(find path from one spot to another; A* is fun)*
- **Formations**
- **Wander** *(if not doing anything, choose a destination, and go there)*
- **Idle** *(Wait for a new command)*

### AI Decision Handling

- **Target Aggro**
- **Target Tank**
- **Target Player**
- **Target Weakest**
- **Flee or Evade if low health**

### AI Balancing

- **Update in Intervals** *(Make new decision once per second, 2 seconds, every tick, etc)*
- **Awareness** *(Make multiple attention/awareness radii.  Only react to certain objects within specific radii)*

Comment: Thanks a bunch! What was really key for me was to only make decisions in intervals, not every tick. Thanks!